# Qualcomm Wifi adaptor disabled by hard switch on toshiba laptop

Tags: wireless

The f12 hardware key is not respondant, and rfkill only unblocks the soft key. I have no idea what the issue is.
 It is an Athenos Adaptor and I have scoured the internet and found nothing. Countless terminal commands have failed, and nothing is in Bios.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit to include the Toshiba model number and the result of `lsmod` thanks